# How to define a custom theme or colors with Astro and Tailwind css

Tags: tailwind-css, nrwl, astrojs

I have a monorepo (Nrwl) in which I have an Astro app which uses Tailwind css.

Everything is running fine, but now I would like to do something with colors / theming

My `tailwind.config.cjs' contains the following:

```
const {
    createGlobPatternsForDependencies,
} = require('@nxtensions/astro/tailwind');
const { join } = require('path');

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [
        join(
            __dirname,
            'src/**/!(*.stories|*.spec).{astro,html,js,jsx,md,svelte,ts,tsx,vue}'
        ),
        ...createGlobPatternsForDependencies(__dirname),
   ],
   theme: {
       extend: {},
   },
   plugins: [],
};
```

Now, when I google I find theme configs like this

```
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
    /**
     * Color Palette - Purple Heart
     */
     purpleheart: {
        colors: {
            primary: colors.purple[700],
            secondary: colors.purple[800],
            dark: {
                primary: colors.purple[300],
                secondary: colors.purple[500]
            },
            accent: {
                gray: {
                    light: colors.gray[300],
                    dark: colors.gray[500]
                },
                default: colors.blue[700]
            }
        }
    },
    ...
```

More examples of this can be found on the Tailwind site itself [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme).

But nowhere it is explained how I can integrate this into my config. Any suggestions how I can use this or create my own colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is a page in the documentation about color customization](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors) that may be of interest to you.

For adding additional colors to Tailwind, define color values in `theme.extend.colors`. You can arbitrarily nest as many objects as you'd like:

```js
const {
    createGlobPatternsForDependencies,
} = require('@nxtensions/astro/tailwind');
const { join } = require('path');

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [
        join(
            __dirname,
            'src/**/!(*.stories|*.spec).{astro,html,js,jsx,md,svelte,ts,tsx,vue}'
        ),
        ...createGlobPatternsForDependencies(__dirname),
   ],
   theme: {
       extend: {
           colors: {
               foo: '#123',
               many: {
                   nested: {
                       objects: {
                           here: '#456',
                       },
                   },
               },
           },
       },
   },
   plugins: [],
};
```

This configuration would then give you color values you could use with utility classes like:

```html
<div class="bg-many-nested-objects-here text-foo">
```